# Restore using time machine from an macbook to an macbook pro (first intel)

Tags: macos, macbook, time-machine

My girlfriend have Macbook 10.6.3, the first plastic version. the screen broke an its at service store now. In the mean time, i have tried to restore from hers TM backup to my old macbook pro 10.6.3 (the first intel version). 
Everything seems to work out fine, but when its finish, it says reboot, but nothing happens. 
When i hold down the power button, powering down, and starts again, its come up  with the grey roll down screen "you need to restart your machine again" in different languages. 
I have tried the restore procedure over again 2 times, and every time it ends up like this...

Anyone have a suggestion what to do ?

Thanks - Anders.

Answer (score 3):

did you recover the whole OS? Maybe the OS on the broken MacBook is not compatible to the hardware of the other MB?

Try reinstalling from your Installation DVD and then use the Migration Assistant (which pops up after the installation) to restore the user data from the TM backup. DO NOT RESTORE THE WHOLE OS.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What steps have you taken to troubleshoot the drive(s)?

Certain issues with drives can make it appear that there is a hardware issue, but it could be the free space index, or other issues.  Have you run Disk Warrior on both drives?  (Time Machine & Internal drive).

Also, the kernel panic issue.  Try holding down the left shift key while booting, that will perform a safe boot, and clear the caches.

But overall, I agree with lajuette, unless your restoring onto the same hardware, use the migration utility.  Don't do a full restore.

Answer (score 0):

Install the operating system on the laptop from the Install DVD. During the install process, just create a random Admin user. Once that's up, you can plug in the Time Machine drive. Create a user for your girlfriend, but select to create it by restoring a user from the Time Machine backup. You could also opt to bring back applications at this point. That should get her user back without pulling the whole operating system back. This is how I moved my wife's data from her old PPC iMac to her new Intel Mac Mini.

Comment: I think you even can, during installation but after installing the actual OS, select to recover data from a Time Machine backup.